# Force certain Flexbox items to wrap into a new row, while not wrapping otherwise

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I am working on a navigation bar that (in desktop layout), shows all its elements in one row. It never wraps. I simply set `flex-flow: row nowrap;` and it works fine:

[image]

Now on mobile, some of these items are to be placed in a second row above, that only shows when hovering/clicking the bottom row.
My progress so far is tagging these hiding items with `.hide-on-mobile;` and setting `order: 2;` and `display: none;` on them, so that the items that always show are in front.

[image]

My plan was to then create some sort of "linebreak" after the last `.hide-on-mobile` and have the remaining elements `flexwrap: wrap-reverse;` to the top. From what I understand, a "linebreak" like that would be possible with a pseudo element.

But my main problem is, that I would have to enable wrapping, which might mess up the navigation bar. My client wants to be able to add/remove items on the navigation bar later on. So placing setting the mobile breakpoint to right before such a wrap would occur is not a solution.

**Is there a way to create a manual wrap in flexbox but otherwise prevent it from wrapping automatically? Or is flexbox not the appropriate approach to this layout problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be a good case to use [`display: contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/display). The idea is to wrap items in 2 lines. In mobile view the 2 lines will be display one on the top of the other. In desktop view, thanks to `display: contents` it will be like all the items would have the same parent.

for the demo `.hide-on-mobile` elements visible when you hover the navigation bar.

Please note that I've use a button only because I don't know how to simulate responsive design on stackoverflow code snippet

```js
// js code for the demo only (because I don't know how to simulate responsive view in stackoverflow code snippet)

document.getElementById('mobile').addEventListener('click', evt => {
    document.getElementById('nav').classList.toggle('mobile-view');
});
```

```css
#nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 20px;
}

.sub-nav {
  display: contents;
}


/* the code below should be a in media query  and the class .mobile-view should be removed */

#nav.mobile-view {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  gap: 0;
}

.mobile-view > .sub-nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.mobile-view > .hide-on-mobile {
  order: -1;
  display: none;
}

#nav.mobile-view:hover > .hide-on-mobile {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav id=nav>
  <div class="sub-nav">
    <a href="#">ZEUTEN</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Projects</a>
    <a href="#">Impressum</a>
    <a href="#">Architect</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-nav hide-on-mobile">
    <a href="#">1234567890</a>
    <a href="#">info@gmil.com</a>
    <a href="#">Teaching</a>
    <a href="#">CV</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- only because I don't know how to simulate responsive view in stackoverflow code snippet -->
<button id="mobile">Toggle mobile view</button>
```